# NotifyJS works on one function and not the other even when the code it's exactly the same

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a form that returns a message whether a new value it's added or deleted, this alert returns a message at the top of the screen only on the modify function but not on the submit one, the code it's exactly the same both the JS call and the C# side.

The JS its like this:

```js
 function SubmitForm(form) {

            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);

            var archivo = document.getElementById("FileUpload").Value;
            form.append("FileUpload", archivo);

            if ($(form).valid()) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: form.action,
                    data: $(form).serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.success) {
                            Popup.dialog('close');

                            $('#table').DataTable().ajax.reload()
                            /*NOTIFY ON ADD NOT WORKING*/
                            $.notify(data.message, {
                                globalPosition: "top center",
                                className: "success"
                            })

                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        }

        function Modify(id) {
            if(confirm('You sure you want to modify this record'))
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("Modify","Custom")/' + id,
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.success)
                        {
                            $('#table').DataTable().ajax.reload()
                            /*NOTIFY ON MODIFY WORKING*/
                            $.notify(data.message, {
                                globalPosition: "top center",
                                className: "error"
                            })

                        }
                    }

                });
            }
        }
```

And the C# side of both classes:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(addLic lic, string FileUpload)
    {

        using (Entities1 db = new Entities1())
        {
//DO INSERT STUFF

                db.SaveChanges();

                return Json(new { success = true, message = "Registro guardado exitosamente." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Modify(int id)
    {
        using (Enitities1 db = new Entities1())
        {
//DO UPDATE STUFF
            db.Entry(lic).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(new { success = true, message = "Registros modificados correctamente." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Am I running Notify.JS the wrong way on the add notification? Can I call it other way?

Comment: Did u find any answer? I have the same problem

Comment: Nope, I gave up and ended up reloading the page each time a new row is added, sketchy but less noticeable. @DanielLima